# Exclude a word if it is present in an array of words

Tags: c

Considering this code that counts all occurrences, how do you remove common words?

> For example, if the word is from the top 100 English words then, *don't count* that word.

If you take the most common 100 words according to Wikipedia, how do you add those to an array and check to not count them on the list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English

**Top 100 most common words in an array form:**

```
#define NUMBER_OF_STRING 100
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE   50

char commonWords[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE] = {"the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in", "that", "have", "I", "it", "for", "not", "on", "with", "he", "as", "you", "do", "at", "this", "but", "his", "by", "from", "they", "we", "say", "her", "she", "or", "an", "will", "my", "one", "all", "would", "there", "their", "what", "so", "up", "out", "if", "about", "who", "get", "which", "go", "me", "when", "make", "can", "like", "time", "no", "just", "him", "know", "take", "people", "into", "year", "your", "good", "some", "could", "them", "see", "other", "than", "then", "now", "look", "only", "come", "its", "over", "think", "also", "back", "after", "use", "two", "how", "our", "work", "first", "well", "way", "even", "new", "want", "because", "any", "these", "give", "day", "most", "us"};
```

**Code Example:**

```
/**
 * C program to count occurrences of all words in a file.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_WORD  20000     /* max word size */
#define MAX_WORDS     8     /* initial number of struct to allocate */

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX   2048     /* max path (defined for Linux in limits.h) */
#endif

typedef struct {            /* use a struct to hold */
    char word[MAX_WORD];    /* lowercase word, and */
    int cap, count;         /* if it appeast capitalized, and its count */
} words_t;

char *strlwr (char *str)    /* no need for unsigned char */
{
    char *p = str;

    while (*p) {
        *p = tolower(*p);
        p++;
    }

    return str;
}

int main (void) {

    FILE *fptr;
    char path[PATH_MAX], word[MAX_WORD];
    size_t i, len, index = 0, max_words = MAX_WORDS;

    /* pointer to allocated block of max_words struct initialized zero */
    words_t *words = calloc (max_words, sizeof *words);
    if (!words) {   /* valdiate every allocation */
        perror ("calloc-words");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Input file path */
    printf ("Enter file path: ");
    if (scanf ("%s", path) != 1) {  /* validate every input */
        fputs ("error: invalid file path or cancellation.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    fptr = fopen (path, "r");   /* open file */
    if (fptr == NULL) {         /* validate file open */
        fputs ( "Unable to open file.\n"
                "Please check you have read privileges.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) {  /* while valid word read */
        int iscap = 0, isunique = 1;    /* is captial, is unique flags */

        if (isupper (*word))            /* is the word uppercase */
            iscap = 1;

        /* remove all trailing punctuation characters */
        len = strlen (word);                    /* get length */
        while (len && ispunct(word[len - 1]))   /* only if len > 0 */
            word[--len] = 0;

        strlwr (word);                  /* convert word to lowercase */

        /* check if word exits in list of all distinct words */
        for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i].word, word) == 0) {
                isunique = 0;               /* set unique flag zero */
                if (iscap)                  /* if capital flag set */
                    words[i].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
                words[i].count++;           /* increment word count */
                break;                      /* bail - done */
            }
        }
        if (isunique) { /* if unique, add to array, increment index */
            if (index == max_words) {       /* is realloc needed? */
                /* always use a temporary pointer with realloc */
                void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * max_words * sizeof *words);
                if (!tmp) { /* validate every allocation */
                    perror ("realloc-words");
                    break;  /* don't exit, original data still valid */
                }
                words = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to words */
                /* (optional) set all new memory to zero */
                memset (words + max_words, 0, max_words * sizeof *words);
                max_words *= 2; /* update max_words to reflect new limit */
            }
            memcpy (words[index].word, word, len + 1);  /* have len */
            if (iscap)                      /* if cap flag set */
                words[index].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
            words[index++].count++;         /* increment count & index */
        }
    }
    fclose (fptr);  /* close file */

    /*
     * Print occurrences of all words in file.
     */
    puts ("\nOccurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:");
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (words[i].cap) {
            strcpy (word, words[i].word);
            *word = toupper (*word);
            /*
             * %-15s prints string in 15 character width.
             * - is used to print string left align inside
             * 15 character width space.
             */
            printf("%-8d %s\n", words[i].count, word);
        }
    }
    free (words);

    return 0;
}
```

**Text File to Test: (cars.txt)**

```
A car (or automobile) is a wheeled motor vehicle used for transportation. Most definitions of car say they run primarily on roads, seat one to eight people, have four tires, and mainly transport people rather than goods.[2][3]

Cars came into global use during the 20th century, and developed economies depend on them. The year 1886 is regarded as the birth year of the modern car when German inventor Karl Benz patented his Benz Patent-Motorwagen. Cars became widely available in the early 20th century. One of the first cars accessible to the masses was the 1908 Model T, an American car manufactured by the Ford Motor Company. Cars were rapidly adopted in the US, where they replaced animal-drawn carriages and carts, but took much longer to be accepted in Western Europe and other parts of the world.

Cars have controls for driving, parking, passenger comfort, and a variety of lights. Over the decades, additional features and controls have been added to vehicles, making them progressively more complex. These include rear reversing cameras, air conditioning, navigation systems, and in-car entertainment. Most cars in use in the 2010s are propelled by an internal combustion engine, fueled by the combustion of fossil fuels. Electric cars, which were invented early in the history of the car, began to become commercially available in 2008.

There are costs and benefits to car use. The costs include acquiring the vehicle, interest payments (if the car is financed), repairs and maintenance, fuel, depreciation, driving time, parking fees, taxes, and insurance.[4] The costs to society include maintaining roads, land use, road congestion, air pollution, public health, health care, and disposing of the vehicle at the end of its life. Road traffic accidents are the largest cause of injury-related deaths worldwide.[5]

The benefits include on-demand transportation, mobility, independence, and convenience.[6] The societal benefits include economic benefits, such as job and wealth creation from the automotive industry, transportation provision, societal well-being from leisure and travel opportunities, and revenue generation from the taxes. People's ability to move flexibly from place to place has far-reaching implications for the nature of societies.[7] There are around 1 billion cars in use worldwide. The numbers are increasing rapidly, especially in China, India and other newly industrialized countries.[8]
```

**Current output:**

```
Occurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:
3        A
2        Motor
2        Most
2        One
8        Cars
29       The
1        German
1        Karl
2        Benz
1        Patent-motorwagen
1        Model
1        T
1        American
1        Ford
1        Company
1        Us
1        Western
1        Europe
1        Over
1        These
1        Electric
2        There
2        Road
1        People's
1        China
1        India
```

**Expected Output: (Example only)**

```
2        Motor
1        German
1        Karl
2        Benz
1        Patent-motorwagen
1        Model
1        T
1        American
1        Ford
1        Company
```

**EDIT Update: 
Possible Solutions:**

while and continue (doesn't work)

```
// skip the word if it is a common word
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
    if (strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make an array with the top 100 words, then when you read the file word by word (as you already do) simply check if it's inside the array. in that case, `continue` the `while`.

Comment: You shouldn't stuff the whole functionality into `main`. Use functions.

Comment: you can remove first every words you don't want, with RegEx in example

Comment: @cid C does not have RegEx

Comment: ... and where is your attempt? There is absolutely no code that filters out the most common words. You need to show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a place where you can ask people to write code for you. You should know that with 665 rep.

Comment: if (word == commonWord) {
continue;
} @Jabberwocky

Comment: You don't compare strings with `==` You're just comparing pointers, that way

Comment: @jaycodez there is no attempt, where is your code?

Comment: I think `strcmp(word, commonWord[i])` will work better.

Comment: @WeatherVane thats a better option

Comment: Thank you, but `if (strcmp(words[i].word, word) == 0)` is *already in your code*.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah I'd prefer to have it in functions rather than all in main...

Comment: @WeatherVane please see update above...

Comment: So you have edited, your question with a solution, so what's the question now? What are you asking now?

Comment: @Jabberwocky it isn't a solution because it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand how is your expected output different from current output? Is your expected output obtained by discarding all the common words from the current output?

Comment: @rv7 yes as ("the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in"... etc)... are common words in the english language...

Comment: From `man tolower`: *"The standards require that the argument c for these functions is
       either EOF or a value that is representable in the type unsigned
       char.  If the argument c is of type char, it must be cast to unsigned
       char, as in the following example:
           `char c;  ...  res = toupper((unsigned char) c);`
       This is necessary because char may be the equivalent of signed char,
       in which case a byte where the top bit is set would be sign extended
       when converting to int, yielding a value that is outside the range of
       unsigned char."*

Comment: If you had `commonWords` sorted it would be much faster.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Why would it be faster if it was sorted?

Comment: @jaycodez searching through a sorted array is obviously faster than going through the whole array (O(log n) vs O(n)). And the fastest way is using a hash table, which is O(1)

Comment: You could use `bsearch` (`<stdlib.h>`) if the array was sorted. I don't know how much faster a hash table will be, and I also don't know how much more space it will need. You could try both, and see the results.

Comment: I would suggest to implement a custom binary search, it's simple, there is a very useful feature that the `bsearch` of `stdlib` does not implement, when a key is not found it tells you exactly where it should be inserted (useful for creating ordered arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly more efficient way would be to use a single call to `strstr` rather than attempting to compare against every one of the top 100 most common words. Since you know the 100 most common words, and they will not change, you can easily determine the longest of the is 7-characters. In other words, you only need to test whether `word` is one of the most common if it is less than:

```
#define TOP_LEN       8     /* longest string in TOP100 + nul-character */
```

Since the words do not change, you can go ahead and:

```
const char TOP100[] = " the be to of and a in that have i it for not on with"
                " he as you do at this but his by from they we say her she or"
                " an will my one all would there their what so up out if about"
                " who get which go me when make can like time no just him know"
                " take people into year your good some could them see other"
                " than then now look only come its over think also back after"
                " use two how our work first well way even new want because"
                " any these give day most us ";
```

(**note:** the `space` before and the `space` after each word which allows you to create a `teststr` to search for with `strstr` by including a space on either side of your word. `'I'` has been converted to lowercase to work after your `strlwr (word);`)

(**also note:** you could also use a constant literal with `#define TOP100 " the ... us "`, but it would wrap and scroll horribly off the page here -- up to you)

With your constant string of the 100 most common words, the only addition needed is:

```
        ...
        strlwr (word);                  /* convert word to lowercase */

        /* check against 100 most common words (TOP100) */
        if (len < TOP_LEN) {                    /* word less than TOP_LEN? */
            char teststr[TOP_LEN * 2];          /* buffer for " word " */
            sprintf (teststr, " %s ", word);    /* create teststr */
            if (strstr (TOP100, teststr))       /* check if in TOP100 */
                continue;                       /* if so, get next word */
        }
        ...
```

You see above, you check if the word is 7-characters or less (otherwise there is no need to check against the most common). You then declare a `teststr` to hold you string with a space at each end. (since the longest common word in 7-char, then 7-char plus 2-spaces is 9-char, plus the *nul-character is* 10, so 16-char is more than adequate here.)

A simple call to `sprintf` is all that is needed to put the spaces at each end of `word`, and then a single call to `strstr` is all that is needed to see if `word` is within the top 100 most common words. If it is, no need to go further, just `continue` and get the next word.

Putting it altogether in your code you would have:

```
/**
 * C program to count occurrences of all words in a file.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_WORD  20000     /* max word size */
#define MAX_WORDS     8     /* initial number of struct to allocate */
#define TOP_LEN       8     /* longest string in TOP100 */

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX   2048     /* max path (defined for Linux in limits.h) */
#endif

const char TOP100[] = " the be to of and a in that have i it for not on with"
                " he as you do at this but his by from they we say her she or"
                " an will my one all would there their what so up out if about"
                " who get which go me when make can like time no just him know"
                " take people into year your good some could them see other"
                " than then now look only come its over think also back after"
                " use two how our work first well way even new want because"
                " any these give day most us ";

typedef struct {            /* use a struct to hold */
    char word[MAX_WORD];    /* lowercase word, and */
    int cap, count;         /* if it appeast capitalized, and its count */
} words_t;

char *strlwr (char *str)    /* no need for unsigned char */
{
    char *p = str;

    while (*p) {
        *p = tolower(*p);
        p++;
    }

    return str;
}

int main (void) {

    FILE *fptr;
    char path[PATH_MAX], word[MAX_WORD];
    size_t i, len, index = 0, max_words = MAX_WORDS;

    /* pointer to allocated block of max_words struct initialized zero */
    words_t *words = calloc (max_words, sizeof *words);
    if (!words) {   /* valdiate every allocation */
        perror ("calloc-words");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Input file path */
    printf ("Enter file path: ");
    if (scanf ("%s", path) != 1) {  /* validate every input */
        fputs ("error: invalid file path or cancellation.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    fptr = fopen (path, "r");   /* open file */
    if (fptr == NULL) {         /* validate file open */
        fputs ( "Unable to open file.\n"
                "Please check you have read privileges.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) {  /* while valid word read */
        int iscap = 0, isunique = 1;    /* is captial, is unique flags */

        if (isupper (*word))            /* is the word uppercase */
            iscap = 1;

        /* remove all trailing punctuation characters */
        len = strlen (word);                    /* get length */
        while (len && ispunct(word[len - 1]))   /* only if len > 0 */
            word[--len] = 0;

        strlwr (word);                  /* convert word to lowercase */

        /* check against 100 most common words (TOP100) */
        if (len < TOP_LEN) {                    /* word less than TOP_LEN? */
            char teststr[TOP_LEN * 2];          /* buffer for " word " */
            sprintf (teststr, " %s ", word);    /* create teststr */
            if (strstr (TOP100, teststr))       /* check if in TOP100 */
                continue;                       /* if so, get next word */
        }

        /* check if word exits in list of all distinct words */
        for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i].word, word) == 0) {
                isunique = 0;               /* set unique flag zero */
                if (iscap)                  /* if capital flag set */
                    words[i].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
                words[i].count++;           /* increment word count */
                break;                      /* bail - done */
            }
        }
        if (isunique) { /* if unique, add to array, increment index */
            if (index == max_words) {       /* is realloc needed? */
                /* always use a temporary pointer with realloc */
                void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * max_words * sizeof *words);
                if (!tmp) { /* validate every allocation */
                    perror ("realloc-words");
                    break;  /* don't exit, original data still valid */
                }
                words = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to words */
                /* (optional) set all new memory to zero */
                memset (words + max_words, 0, max_words * sizeof *words);
                max_words *= 2; /* update max_words to reflect new limit */
            }
            memcpy (words[index].word, word, len + 1);  /* have len */
            if (iscap)                      /* if cap flag set */
                words[index].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
            words[index++].count++;         /* increment count & index */
        }
    }
    fclose (fptr);  /* close file */

    /*
     * Print occurrences of all words in file.
     */
    puts ("\nOccurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:");
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (words[i].cap) {
            strcpy (word, words[i].word);
            *word = toupper (*word);
            /*
             * %-15s prints string in 15 character width.
             * - is used to print string left align inside
             * 15 character width space.
             */
            printf("%-8d %s\n", words[i].count, word);
        }
    }
    free (words);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

As was the case last time, your **Expected Output: (Example only)** is wrong because there is nothing in your code to remove *plurals*, *possessives* or *plural possessives*, so your output with your `cars.txt` file would be:

```
$ ./bin/unique_words_exclude_top_100
Enter file path: dat/cars.txt

Occurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:
2        Motor
8        Cars
1        German
1        Karl
2        Benz
1        Patent-motorwagen
1        Model
1        T
1        American
1        Ford
1        Company
1        Western
1        Europe
1        Electric
2        Road
1        People's
1        China
1        India
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 3):

filter out `common word` before adding `word` into `words` list.
I made the fiter function as below:

```
int isCommonWord(char * word)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
        if (strcmp(commonWords[i], word) == 0) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And, filter out word before adding to words array.
Please refer the 2nd line of the code what i modified as below:

```
if (isunique) { /* if unique, add to array, increment index */
    if (!isCommonWord(word)) {
        if (index == max_words) {       /* is realloc needed? */
            /* always use a temporary pointer with realloc */
            void *tmp = realloc(words, 2 * max_words * sizeof *words);
            if (!tmp) { /* validate every allocation */
                perror("realloc-words");
                break;  /* don't exit, original data still valid */
            }
            words = (words_t *)tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to words */
            /* (optional) set all new memory to zero */
            memset(words + max_words, 0, max_words * sizeof *words);
            max_words *= 2; /* update max_words to reflect new limit */
        }
        memcpy(words[index].word, word, len + 1);  /* have len */
        if (iscap)                      /* if cap flag set */
            words[index].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
        words[index++].count++;         /* increment count & index */
    }
}
```

I think The result is correct as below:

```
Enter file path: cars.txt

Occurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:
2        Motor
8        Cars
1        German
1        Karl
2        Benz
1        Patent-motorwagen
1        Model
1        T
1        American
1        Ford
1        Company
1        Western
1        Europe
1        Electric
2        Road
1        People's
1        China
1        India
```

Answer (score 2):

This obviously doesn't work, because it isn't *skipping the word if it is a common word* like in the misleading comment, but skip the current **iteration** and continue checking with the next word in the common words list

```
// skip the word if it is a common word
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
    if (strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

`continue` will only affect the innermost loop. Besides, after the loop **nothing is changed**

To fix that you need to break the outer loop

```
nextword:
while (fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) // read the word
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
        if (strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0) {
            goto nextword; // skip current word
        }
    }
/// ...
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `goto` then another variable must be used

```
int isCommonWord = 0;
while (fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) // read the word
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
        if (strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0) {
            isCommonWord = 1;
            break; // exit the for loop
        }
    }
    if (isCommonWord)
        continue;  // get the next word
/// ...
}
```

Anyway your implementation is quite inefficient. This is basically a [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) that maps from a string (the word) to integer (which is the word count). The dictionary can be sorted (like `std::map` in C++) or [hash-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array#Hash_table_implementations) (`std::unordered_map` in C++). Since you don't sort the array you always have to traverse through the whole list. If the array is sorted then using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) will cut down the lookup significantly. To check a list of 128 elements you need only at most 7 comparisons instead of 128 like in the case of unsorted list

But before looking for the word in the dictionary you need to check if the word is common or not first. That's done by checking if the word exists in the common word [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) or not. Again the set can be implemented unsorted (slow), sorted (better, `std::set` in C++) or hash-based (fastest but needs more memory, `std::unordered_set` in C++). The difference between the set and the dictionary is that each dictionary entry contains a pair of (key, value), whereas the value is also the key in a set. The `for` loop checking `strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0` above is a simple set traversing. In any case, once you've found the word in the set, skip the current `while` loop and **not** the `for` loop like I said above. That'll work

Answer (score 0):

Continuing outer loops is a case where `goto` is recommended.

Add a label before the while:

```
outer:
while (fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1)  { ... }
```

And change the possible solution in the question to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
    if (strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0) {
        goto outer;
    }
}
```

In your current solution, `continue` simply continues the inner for loop.

EDIT

---

Based on your program, modifying the program as follows should work:

```
.
.
.

outer:
while (fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) {
    .
    .
    .

    strlwr(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
        if (strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0) {
            goto outer;
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
}

.
.
.
```

A function for this would look like:

```
int isCommon(char *word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
        if (strcmp(word, commonWords[i])==0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    .
    .
    .

    while (fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) {
        .
        .
        .

        strlwr(word);

        if(isCommon(word))
            continue;

        .
        .
        .
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Note that if using this function, you no longer need `goto`; a simple `continue` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, the solution does not fix the problem of skipping common words from being added to the list of words as per the running program.

Comment: Bonus: do you know how to add that to a function?

Comment: @jaycodez  goto?   see the code from my answer.   It is the function.

Comment: `continue` is also not good way because programmer must always consider codes from  the below of `continue` to the end of loop. It is not good for a maintainability even though this code works now. So, I suggest `if statement`.